# Extension 'Rome' is configured as formatter but it cannot format 'TypeScript'-files

Tags: vscode-extensions, rome

I'm experiencing this problem with VSCode with the extension, Rome 0.28.0, installed.
My `.vscode/settings.json` includes

```
{
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "rome.rome",
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "rome.rome"
    }
}
```

I've tried disabling and re-enabling the extension, installing different versions of the extension, restarting VSCode, etc.